# How to estimate test execution using testlink

Tags: testlink

I have gone through many articles and all are suggested me to create custom fields/Keywords in testlink to estimate the time for sprint execution.

Articles like :-

http://www.softwaretestingconcepts.com/testlink-using-custom-fields-and-keywords-for-effective-testing

Is there any alternative approach or any scientific method to estimate your sprint execution accurately.

I have found one article proposing below method:-

**Number of Test Cases = (Number of Function Points) × 1.2**

Source :- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/estimation_techniques/estimation_techniques_testing.htm

What should be the approach to estimating your execution cycle? Currently, I am doing it as per my experience in my project. It is working fine but management wants a concrete mechanism for same. Please suggest and share your experience

I have added Time Estimate and Actual Time from below option:-

[image]

Below is the result of above setting

[image]

[image]

I am not able to get this field data in report. I need total estimate also and then comparison between actual and estimated time

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 2):

TestLink provides inbuilt support to record Estimated Exec. time(define at TestCase creation) [image: Estimated Exec. time define at TestCase creation] and Actual Execution time. (record at TestCase Execution time)
[image]

Based on this feature hopes you can buildup your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I am using test link 1.9.5 and there is a option is Time Estimate .. I believe it is the same one as Estimated time in your testlink.... But How to get that Execution duration as you have in your 2nd image

Comment: Can test link record time automatically like we start the time when start executing same and then stop once testcase done

Comment: I have added the images in my question .. Please verify are you asking for same

Comment: TestLink can't automatically record execution time.To get Execution duration   field AFAIR we need to set a config in TestLink. Please read the TestLink manual, It should mention how to do that

Comment: Check https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-documentation/wiki/Execution-Feature---Configuration

Comment: How to get this data in Test result report?

Comment: I am not able to get this field data in reports. I need total estimate also and then comparison between actual and estimated time .. Do you have some setting for same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120103/discussion-between-asanka-vithanage-and-shubham-jain).